# How to kill a Rhino script

Tags: java, rhino

We are using Rhino to execute Javascript inside our Java app. We make use of some Rhino-specific features so we can’t upgrade to Nashorn.
The problem we have is that scripts are created by users, and when we execute them, if there is a mistake like an infinite loop, it keeps executing forever. We want to set a time limit of something like 30 seconds.
Is there a way to kill a script when the timeout is hit?

Comment: How are you launching those scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should extend the `ContextFactory` class and override the method `observeInstructionCount(Context ctx, int instructionCount)`. This method will be called periodically by Rhino and you can check how long it has been running so far with something like this:

```
public class ScriptDynamicScopeFactory extends ContextFactory {
    @Override
    protected Context makeContext() {
        ScriptContext ctx = new ScriptContext();
        ctx.setInstructionObserverThreshold(10000);
        return ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void observeInstructionCount(Context ctx, int instructionCount) {
      long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long executionTime = (currentTime - ((ScriptContext) ctx).startTime());
      // do something if execution time is greater then your timeout
    }
}
```

Notice that you also need to override `makeContext()` to set how often your observer will be called. Keep in mind that this is the number of instructions executed, which means that it won't get called consistently every X ms. If one instruction takes a lot (for example, calling your Java app), this might not work well, but I think it will do a good job in almost all cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop loop from running by creating a dummy debugger and add it to the javascript directly like this:

```
mContext = Context.enter();
ObservingDebugger observingDebugger = new ObservingDebugger();
mContext.setDebugger(observingDebugger, new Integer(0));
mContext.setGeneratingDebug(true);
mContext.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
```

Then through the java program, you create a class that looks like this:

```
public class ObservingDebugger implements Debugger 
{
boolean isDisconnected = false;

private DebugFrame debugFrame = null;

public boolean isDisconnected() {
    return isDisconnected;
}

public void setDisconnected(boolean isDisconnected) {
    this.isDisconnected = isDisconnected;
    if(debugFrame != null){
       ((ObservingDebugFrame)debugFrame).setDisconnected(isDisconnected);
    }
}

public ObservingDebugger() {

}

public DebugFrame getFrame(Context cx, DebuggableScript fnOrScript)
{
    if(debugFrame == null){
        debugFrame = new ObservingDebugFrame(isDisconnected);
    }
    return debugFrame;      
}

@Override
public void handleCompilationDone(Context arg0, DebuggableScript arg1, String arg2) {   } }
// internal ObservingDebugFrame class
class ObservingDebugFrame implements DebugFrame
   {
boolean isDisconnected = false;

public boolean isDisconnected() {
    return isDisconnected;
}

public void setDisconnected(boolean isDisconnected) {
    this.isDisconnected = isDisconnected;
}

ObservingDebugFrame(boolean isDisconnected)
{
    this.isDisconnected = isDisconnected;
}

public void onEnter(Context cx, Scriptable activation,
        Scriptable thisObj, Object[] args)
{ }

public void onLineChange(Context cx, int lineNumber) 
{
    if(isDisconnected){
        throw new RuntimeException("Script Execution terminaed");
    }
}

public void onExceptionThrown(Context cx, Throwable ex)
{ }

public void onExit(Context cx, boolean byThrow,
        Object resultOrException)
{ }

@Override
public void onDebuggerStatement(Context arg0) { } }
```

Then to set the timer of the program, you import:

```
import java.util.Timer;
```

Then you set your timer prefernece for the ObservingDebugger:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   // code here
  }
}, 2*60*1000);
// Since Java-8
timer.schedule(() -> /* your database code here */, 2*60*1000);
```